# Why do browsers append extra line breaks at the end of the body tag?

Tags: html, dom, specifications

When loading an HTML document I find that the DOM body content is inconsistent with the body content in the HTML document.

For example, if you go to [example.com](http://example.com) the end of the HTML document looks like this:

```
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would expect the last child node of body to be `\n`.

However, when I access the DOM in JavaScript the `textContent` of the last child node is `\n\n\n`.

I tried this in Chrome and Firefox and both behave in the same way. What is the explanation for this behavior?

Comment: interesting. looks like all `\n` are counted after the last closing tag untill the end of the document (so even line breaks after `</html>` count)

Comment: @RolandStarke Wow, thanks for pointing that out! That's indeed what's happening. What a strange thing!